# $provide.decorator $controller return throw undefined is not a function angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to add dynamic controller's script when the controller loaded via view.

Here is my files tree:

- index.html
- app.js
- views

  - prod.html
  - cat.html
- controllers

  - prod.js
  - cat.js

I want that when the user get `/prod/` URL the app will load (in the view) the prod.html and the `prod.js` for the controller's logic dynamically. 
All this logic required ng-route of course.

**Index.html**

```html
<body data-ng-app="myApp">
  <div data-ng-view=""></div>  
</body>
```

**Default.js**
using AngularJS v1.3.14

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $controllerProvider, $provide) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });

    app.registerCtrl = $controllerProvider.register;

    $routeProvider.
      when('/:name', {
          templateUrl: function (urlAttr) {
              return '/views/' + urlAttr.name + '.html';
          }
      });

    // This code throw error: 
    //TypeError: undefined is not a function
    //at angular.min.js:1
    //at r (angular.min.js:1)
    //at at (angular.min.js:1)
    //at b (angular.min.js:1)
    //at b (angular.min.js:1)
    //at b (angular.min.js:1)
    //at b (angular.min.js:1)
    //at $get.t (angular.min.js:1)
    //at angular.min.js:1
    //at p.$get.p.$eval (angular.min.js:1)
    $provide.decorator('$controller', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
      // I want to get the controller name and than load the js file.
      //    return function (constructor, locals) {
      //        if (typeof constructor == "string") {
      //            locals.$scope.loadControllerScript(constructor);
      //        }
      //        return $delegate(constructor, locals);
      //    }
    }]);
});
```

**Prod.html**

```html
<div class="row" data-ng-controller="prodCtrl">
{{test}}  
</div>
```

**Prod.js**

```html
app.registerCtrl('prodCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.test = '';
});
```

The problem is the error: **"undefined is not a function"**. (See the code in Default.js)
**If the question is not clear, I will be happy to explain more.**

Comment: Can you show the code where you provide the loadControllerScript function?

Comment: It's not relevant. The exception thrown in "$provide.decorator('$controller', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {" - before the "loadControllerScript". I will update my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot ask for instances (e.g $controller) during the configuration phase. You can only access providers there. Check the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module):

> **Configuration blocks** - get executed during the provider registrations and configuration phase. Only providers and constants
>   can be injected into configuration blocks. This is to prevent
>   accidental instantiation of services before they have been fully
>   configured.

UPDATE: This works:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ng'], ['$provide', function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$controller', ['$delegate',  function($delegate) {
        return function(constructor, locals) {
            console.log("executing custom code ...");
            return $delegate(constructor, locals);
        }
    }])
}]);
```

Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5b9v4hjk/32/)

Comment: So, where can I run a code that will load the controller's script dynamically?

Comment: Thanks! It's working. Now, I get another error "object is not a function" in angular code script in line 7698 (uncompressed version) "forEach(controllers, function(controller) {"
I'm using angular v1.3.14.

Comment: There seems to be compatibility issues. The code only works for Angular 1.2.x or below.

Comment: For Angular 1.3.x and later, return the delegate fn as `return $delegate(constructor, locals, true);`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442605/angularjs-decorate-controllers/32443053#32443053