# Angularjs - Decorate Controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-decorator

I am trying to set up a decorator for my controllers. My intention is to introduce some common behaviour across all the controllers in my app.

I have it configured to work in Angular 1.2.x, but there are some breaking changes from 1.3.x onwards that is breaking the code. The error one now gets is **"controller is not a function"**.

Below is the code for the decorator:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ng'], function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$controller', function($delegate) {

        return function(constructor, locals) {

                //Custom behaviour code

                return $delegate(constructor, locals);
            }
        })
    });
```

Angular 1.2.x - http://jsfiddle.net/3v17w364/2/  (Working) 
Angular 1.4.x - http://jsfiddle.net/tncquyxo/2/  (Broken)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Angular 1.4.x modules have [decorator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#decorator) method, `$provide.decorator` is no longer needed.

For monkey-patching APIs it is always preferable to use `arguments` instead of enumerating them explicitly, the chance that it will break is much lesser.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ng']).decorator('$controller', function ($delegate) {
    return function (constructor, locals) {
        var controller = $delegate.apply(null, arguments);

        return angular.extend(function () {
            locals.$scope.common = ...;
            return controller();
        }, controller);
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you direct me towards any documentation for how `arguments` got injected. I am splits as to where that variable came from.

Comment: Check the docs on [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), they should help.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question.

Had to dig in to Angular source code to figure out whats going on.

The $controller instance is created using below code. The fix lay in the parameter '**later**'. This needs to be set to **true**.

```
    return function(expression, locals, later, ident) {
      // PRIVATE API:
      //   param `later` --- indicates that the controller's constructor is invoked at a later time.
      //                     If true, $controller will allocate the object with the correct
      //                     prototype chain, but will not invoke the controller until a returned
      //                     callback is invoked.
```

Above taken from: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.js

Updated provider code:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ng'], function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$controller', function($delegate) {

 return function(constructor, locals) {

            //Custom behaviour code

            return $delegate(constructor, locals, true);
        }
    })
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v3067u98/1/

Comment: Omitted `ident` argument will screw up controllerAs controllers.

Comment: Thanks for the note. Could you say more about how would it screw it up? See following fiddle with a controllerAs controller that works with the same decorater: http://jsfiddle.net/04y5w1ts/

Comment: Sure, here's how. http://jsfiddle.net/5as9yyn6/ Note in the console that `constructor` is provided to $controller as it was specified. "myController as myc" string already contains controller identifier, that's why it worked for you.