# Why Can't I Decorate a Controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The AngularJS (1.x) developer guide goes into great detail about how to decorate Services, Directives, and Filters. For some reason, it mentions nothing about decorating controllers.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators

To me, it would seem logical that one would be able decorate a controller. After all, it's just a class constructor, much like a service definition. When I try to decorate my controller, however, I get "Unknown provider" errors.

Here's my code:

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('MyController',  function(){
  this.message1 = 'Hey there';
  this.message2 = 'Whats up?';
})

angular.module('app').decorator('MyController', function($delegate){
  // TODO: Add some decorating here
  return $delegate;
})
```

See example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Wxz142vrmuxtQFbXLvVb?p=preview

Am I doing something wrong? Or is decorating a controller just not possible in Angular.

Comment: possibile duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442605/angularjs-decorate-controllers)

Comment: Not a duplicate. If you read both our questions, they are pretty distinct.

Comment: I believe controllers are not available in config phase, which is when decoration method runs. Having said that, you can extend a controller using $controller('controller') and updating/extending its scope. Check this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28791884/provide-decorator-controller-return-throw-undefined-is-not-a-function-angularj